# Method running before previous method is finished, Future Async Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

My method *processData()* is executing before *pullAllData()* is finished but I need *processData()* to wait until *pullAllData()* is completely finished before running. This is causing my *isDownloadSuccessful* bool to be Null when *processData()* is ran.

```
Future getCoinData() async {
    calculateNumberOfDataPoints();
    pullTimesAndPrices();
    return timesAndPrices;
  }

Future pullTimesAndPrices() async {
    for (String cryptoCurrency in cryptoAbbreviation) {
      pullAllData(cryptoCurrency);
      processData(cryptoCurrency);
    }
  }

Future pullAllData(cryptoCurrency) async {
    String historicalRequestURL =
        '$cryptoAPIURL$cryptoCurrency$currency/ohlc?periods=$periodValue&apikey=$apiKey';
    http.Response historicalResponse = await http.get(historicalRequestURL);
    isPullSuccessful = (historicalResponse.statusCode == 200);
  }

void processData(cryptoCurrency) {
    if (isPullSuccessful) {
      ...
    } else {
      throw 'Problem pulling data';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are marking your function `pullTimesAndPrices` as `async` but not using `await`. Use the `await` keyword before calling the `pullAllData` function.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I changed my code to Future<void> pullTimesAndPrices() async {
  

    for (String cryptoCurrency in cryptoAbbreviation) {
      await pullAllData(cryptoCurrency);
      processData(cryptoCurrency);
    }
  }